# What are the downsides of using filesystem for storing uploaded files in django?

Tags: django, storage, django-file-upload

I know about s3 storage but I am trying to see if things can work out by only using filesystem

Comment: Scalability? Imagine that you want to deliver data everywhere on the planet, then if you use a simple filesystem these all have to hit the *same* server, which will render the server unresponsive, and furthermore will require accessing a server at the other side of the plant for some users.

Comment: The main thing S3 delivers is the fact that the files are stored on a *number* of servers, and that you typically access one nearby, and thus minimizing the distance the data has to travel.

Comment: Furthermore due to duplication, if the disk fails, the data is normally *not* lost.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason to use a service like S3 is ***scalability***. Imagine that you use a the file system of a simple server to store files. Then it means that everyone that visits your site and wants to access a file, has to visit the same server. If there are enough visitors, then this will eventually render the system unresponsive.

Scalable storage services will store the same data on *multiple* servers to allow serving the content when the number of requests increases. Furthermore one normally hits a server that is close to the location of that user which ***minimizes the delay*** to fetch a file.

Finally such storage services are ***more reliable***. If you use a single disk to store all the files, it is possible that eventually the disk fails losing all the data. By storing the data on multiple locations, it is less likely that the files are completely lost.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right, I should use a storage service even though my app does not recieve a lot of traffic. Thanks